# Android App Crashes after Sharing using Facebook Dialogs

Tags: android, facebook, multithreading, dialog

I'm trying to integrate Facebook SDK into an Android project. I'm posting a wall message in the Facebook Dialog, when I hit "Share", the message gets posted successfully on my Facebook wall. But my game still crashes!

I call it from my main class that extends Activity. To popup the facebook UI dialogs, I use runOnUiThread. (AsyncTask doesn't work in my code.)

```
public static int fbShareScores( final String sBody ) 
{
try 
{   
  oThis.runOnUiThread ( 
    new Runnable ( ) 
    { 
      @Override
      public void run ( ) 
      { 
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("caption", "Caption");
        params.putString("description", sBody);
    params.putString("picture", URL_TO_PNG);
        params.putString("name", "Name");
        oThis.mFacebook.dialog(oThis, "feed", params, null);
      } 
    } 
  );
}
catch ( Exception e ) 
{ 
  Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "share scores: Dialog: " + e.getMessage());
}

return 1;
}
```

Here are my errors from logcat:

> D/Facebook-WebView(957): Webview loading URL:
>   https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed W/AudioFlinger(32): write blocked
>   for 80 msecs, 275 delayed writes, thread 0xff88 D/dalvikvm(957):
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 539K, 15% free 7403K/8647K, paused 3ms+47ms
>   D/webviewglue(957): nativeDestroy view: 0x925250
>   D/Facebook-WebView(957): Redirect URL:
>   fbconnect://success?post_id=570020602_418386674846932
>   D/AndroidRuntime(957): Shutting down VM W/dalvikvm(957): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(957):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException E/AndroidRuntime(957):     at
>   com.facebook.android.FbDialog$FbWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(FbDialog.java:143)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:219)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:319)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(957):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) W/ActivityManager(67):   Force finishing activity
>   com.companyname.mainclassname/.MainClassName

Comment: Are you at all running it on a different thread than the UI one?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I'm new to Android development. My game's main class' Activity is on a Main Thread, that calls runOnUiThread, which runs the Facebook dialog. FbDialog.java is Facebook's SDK, I don't know if FB is using another thread, I reference it from my game.

Comment: Are you using the regular Facebook class or the *AsyncFacebookRunner*? If you're not using the latter then there's no reason for you to use *runOnUiThread* since you are on the same thread. This has nothing to do with android, it's more of a java thing and even more fundamental: working with threads.

Comment: I'm using Facebook's class. When I don't use runOnUiThread, I get the error related to not being on the UI thread. I managed to bypass this error, by passing in a DialogListener, I had it set to null.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something weird.. Can you please edit your question and add more relevant code?

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, I don't know how it got fixed. But I posted an answer below. Is that incorrect? I'm actually working off of ShiVa3D engine, they export the game into java files for an Android project. It makes it difficult to see which part of their exported engine code is relevant or causing me to use runOnUiThread. But their main java file is using runOnUiThread for other cases, so I ended up using runOnUiThread for Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

The error is gone when I change the line in the above code to:

```
oThis.mFacebook.dialog(oThis, "feed", params, new PostStatusDialogListener());
```

Then add a new DialogListener:

```
public class PostStatusDialogListener implements DialogListener 
{
  @Override
  public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "PostStatusDialogListener::onComplete");
  }

  @Override
  public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
    Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "PostStatusDialogListener::onFacebookError: " + error.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(DialogError error) {
    Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "PostStatusDialogListener::DialogError: " + error.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancel() {
    Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "PostStatusDialogListener::onCancel");
  }
}
```